# Creating a list based on value stored in variable in python

Tags: python

I have a variable with a string value in it.
I want to create a list with the value as its name/identifier, then append values to the list.
So assuming variable `s = "temp1"`, I want to create a list called `temp1`.
Obviously, in my case, I would not know what the value of `s` will be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't. Creating dynamic variables is rarely a good idea, and if you are trying to create local names (inside a function), difficult and greatly affects performance.

Use a dictionary instead:

```
lists = {}
lists[strs] = []
lists[strs].append(somevalue)
```

Namespaces are just default dictionaries for code to look up names in. It is a lot easier and cleaner to create more such dictionaries.

You can still access the global (module namespace with the [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) function, which returns a (writable) dictionary. You can access the function local namespace with [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), but writing to this usually has no effect as local namespace access in functions has been optimized.

In Python 2 you can remove that optimisation by using a `exec` statement in the function. In Python 3, you can no longer switch off the optimisation as the `exec` statement has been replaced by the [`exec()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), which means the compiler can no longer detect with certainty that you are potentially writing to the local namespace with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `globals()`:

```
>>> strs = "temp1"
>>> globals()[strs] = []
>>> temp1
[]
```

But using a dict for such purpose would be more appropriate:

```
>>> dic = {strs:[]}
>>> dic["temp1"]
[]
```