# Naming a variable on the basis of index in loop

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

I want to implement a loop where in each iteration I name the variable according to iterator value. For instance-

```
for i in range(1,10):
    r<value of i> = # some value
```

Is there a way i can do it, other than making all these variables as string keys in a dictionary as mentioned in [How do you create different variable names while in a loop? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop-python). I want each to be a separate variable.

Comment: You should detail what you want to do exactly. I think you have some misunderstanding of what a variable purpose is. Did you consider loading your values into a List ?

Comment: You don't want to do this, /thread

Comment: @AsTeR Yes, I understand what a variable is and I consider using list is a good option here. But using separate variables is required by the problem I am trying to solve. The answer given serves my purpose. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm still curious about your motivation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using `globals()`, but it's a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17167649/846892):

```
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...         globals()['r'+str(i)] = "foo"
...     
>>> r1
'foo'
>>> r2
'foo'
```

Prefer a dict over `globals()`:

```
>>> my_vars = dict()
>>> for i in range(1,10):
        my_vars['r'+str(i)] = "foo"
>>> my_vars['r1']
'foo'
>>> my_vars['r2']
'foo'
```