# Python: Altering code between iterations

Tags: python, loops, syntax, iteration

I have a bit of code that I want to run multiple times. That seams trivial but there is a twist: I want to change the code in a specific way between iterations. For example:

```
A = 1
B = ['+','-','/'.'*','**']
C = []
for x in range(len(B)):
    C.append(A{B[x]}100)
print(C)
```

Now, I know this code doesn't work and it's not a proper Python syntax, but i't just an example of what I'd like the code to do.

Ideally I'd get C as a list where 0th element is 1 + 100, 1st element is 1 - 100, 2nd element is 1 / 100 etc. (N.b.: NOT '1 + 100' string. A result of 1 + 100 calculation - 101). Basically I want the code to change itself between iterations of loop in a defined way.

I do not want to define some lengthy `if`/`elif` statement since list B is very, very long.

Edit:

Let me give another example. This one is more relevant to my problem.

```
A = ['mom','dad','me','you','c']
B = ['a','b','something','nothing','cat']
for x in range(len(A)):
    C_{A[x]} = B[x]
```

I want to end up with 5 new variables so that:

```
Print(C_mom)
a
Print(C_dad)
b
Print(C_c)
cat
```

Again, I recognize this is not a proper python syntax and this code doesn't work.

Comment: What else does `B` contains?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary It's just an example. It can be a list of anything. It's the change of variables name by loop which is the tricky part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a dict where each string `'+'`,`'*'` etc point to it's corresponding method imported from `operator` module.

Now loop over `B` and fetch the corresponding method from the `ops` dict and pass the operands to the method.

```
>>> from operator import add,sub,mul,div,pow
>>> ops = {'+':add,'-':sub,'/':div, '*':mul,'**':pow}
>>> B = ['+','-','/','*','**']
>>> A = 1
>>> [ops[item](A,100) for item in B]
[101, -99, 0, 100, 1]
```

Use `'/': operator.truediv` if you want `ops['/'](1,100)` to return `0.01` instead of `0`.

**Update:**

Creating dynamic variables in python is not a good idea, you should better use a dict here:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> B = ['a','b','something','nothing','cat']
>>> c = {x:y for x,y in zip(A,B)}
>>> c[1]
'a'
>>> c[2]
'b'
>>> c[5]
'cat
```

Use `globals()` to create  dynamic variables(don't use this method):

```
for x,y in zip(A,B):
    globals()['C'+str(x)] =y
...     
>>> C1
'a'
>>> C2
'b'
```

Comment: Or you could just use `B = [add, sub, div, mul, pow]` directly and avoid the extra indirection. Also the OP says B is very long, so presumably it must include other user-defined functions rather than just simple operators.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thank you. It's not compleate solution to my problem though. (See edit)

Comment: @447xpro I've updated my solution, I guess that's what you wanted.

Comment: I'd probably use `dict(zip(A, B))` instead (although I admit you can't perform transformations as easily that way).  You're definitely right that dictionaries are much better than the usual hacks to make dynamic variables.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Again, no. You are using __getitem__ form list C. I want a variable which's name is C1. A could be a list of strings `A = ['car','bike',...]` and I'd need to get Ccar = a, Cbike = b etc. (I've edited the post again to avoid this confusion)

Comment: @447xpro I know what you want, but creating dynamic variables like that is not a good idea. Prefer dict over that.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Why is it not a good idea? Even if it is so and one shouldn't use it, I'd like to learn it nevertheless and the never use it again just for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, Thank you a lot. :) I will do as you advise and not use the last method. It's good to know though.

Comment: @447xpro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167591/creating-a-list-based-on-value-stored-in-variable-in-python/17167649#17167649