# Create and name matrices inside a loop given a simple row vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, backpropagation

I am trying to implement backpropagation by my own. 
Suppose I have a simple vector with whole numbers like the following:
`x=[5,3,6,4]`
What I would like to do is create matrices, using the previous vector or any like that one. Foe example:

`W1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(5,3))
W2 = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(3,6))
W3 = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(6,4))`

How can I achieve this? The main problem, I guess, is that I cannot name and declare all of this matrices inside a for loop. What would be the most appropiate way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of your desired arrays:

```
x=[5,3,6,4]

weights = {'W'+str(i+1): np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(x[i],x[i+1])) 
             for i in range(len(x)-1)}
```

Then, to use them, just call them from that dictionary. For instance, if you want to use `W1`, use:

```
weights['W1']
```

which returns your array:

```
array([[-1.22374486,  0.74080707,  0.00914048],
       [ 0.08813797,  0.6807603 ,  0.87249113],
       [ 0.29799539, -0.78276957,  0.11789963],
       [-0.25467395, -1.27457749,  0.96499082],
       [-2.92436286, -0.8131938 , -2.2352768 ]])
```

You can see a list of all the variables names created using `weights.keys()`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167591/creating-a-list-based-on-value-stored-in-variable-in-python/17167649#17167649)

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks a lot for the clarification. One more question though. When calling the arrays, is there any way to do it, again, in a loop? For example say I wanted to print all arrays without having to type each one of them. What would be the appropiate way of doing it? I tried with something like `print['W'+str(i+1)]` inside the loop but an exception is raised

Comment: Found this, and it worked :D
`for key in weights:
    print(weights[key])`