# How to create list inside for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

How can I create lists using `for` loop to get `list_1`, `list_2`, `list_3`, etc.? (Python)

I tried this:

```
for i in range(5):
i += 1
list_(i) = []
```

But not working.

```
  File test.py, line 3
runner_(i) = []
            ^
```

SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Comment: What happens when you run your code?   What do you expect to happen?  As it is in the question you will just get an Indentation Error and it will stop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic variable name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564140/dynamic-variable-name-in-python)

Comment: did you mean to create a dictionary with `{'list_1': [], 'list_2' = []}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task I would choose a different data structure `dict()`

This will let You map the keys to respective lists such as:

```py
my_dictionary = {}
for i in range(5):
    my_dictionary[f"list_{i}"] = [] # This might be also my_dictionary["list_"+str(i)]
```

Please note that I have used empty list as key -> value mapping.

This in turn will produce a following dictionary:

```
{"list_0": [], "list_1": [], "list_2": [], "list_3":[], "list_4":[]}
```

Comment: or as a dict-comprehension: `{f"list_{i}": [] for i in range(5)}` .

Comment: Exactly as mentioned by @hiroprotagonist which would be a little less readable for some coming from different languages.

Comment: `"list_"+i` will throw an error. You must convert the integer to a string first.

Comment: Ah yes thank You @TedKleinBergman that is true, I am far more used to f-strings.

Answer (score 2):

You may create list of lists:

```
main_list = []
for i in range(5):
    sub_list= []
    main_list.append(sub_list)
print(main_list)
print(main_list[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dic={}
for i in range(5):
    dic[f"list{i}"]= []

print(dic)
```

Comment: this is a example

Comment: In my opinion this is the best way to do what you really want to do

Comment: it makes a dictionary with 5 lists  and you can access the dictionary like accessing a list

Answer (score 1):

Creating multiple variables is not considered Pythonic. If you want to create a series of variables, a good option is to use a list, like so:

```
list_of_lists = []
for i in range(5)
    list_of_lists.append([])
```

When you want to access a specific list:

```
list_of_lists[3]
-> []
```

However, if you would like to maintain the variable names, you could consider using a dictionary, perhaps like so:

```
dict_of_lists = {}
for i in range(5):
    dict_of_lists[f'list_{i}'] = []
```

Accessing:

```
dict_of_lists['list_1']
-> []
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you to not do this at all. Creating dynamic variables is rarely a good idea and it might affects performance. You can always use dictionary instead as it would be more appropriate:

```
lists = {}
lists["list_" + str(i)] = []
lists["list_" + str(i)].append(somevalue)
```

Look here for some more explanation:
[Creating a list based on value stored in variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167591/creating-a-list-based-on-value-stored-in-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use list or dictionary.
But, use the below code for the requirement.

```
     for i in range(5):
         exec("list_%d = []" % (i+1))
```

Comment: You're correct that the OP most likely needs to use a list or a dictionary. There are almost never a situation where `locals`, `globals` or `exec` is the solution. Using `exec` like this is more of a hack that will lead to confusion and potentially many future problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `globals()`:

```
for i in range(5):
  i += 1
  globals()['list_'+str(i)] = []
```

Most awesome, cool and pythonic way is BTW to use a dictionary man ;-)

```
list_dicts = {}
for i in range(5):
  i += 1
  list_dicts['list_'+str(i)] = []
```

And retrive/edit like:

```
list_dicts['list_2']
```

Tired of the sucking `for` loop? Time for dict comprehension:

```
list_dicts = {'list_'+str(i): [] for i in range(5)}
```

Comment: There are almost never a situation where `locals`, `globals` or `exec` is the solution. So while `globals` works in this case, it's definitely not the correct approach. It's more of a hack that will lead to confusion and future problems. Your other suggestions are much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for the `locals()` function, this function holds all the local variables. you could then write something like this.

```py
for i in range(5):
   locals()["list_"+str(i)] = []
```

Comment: While it works, it's definitely not the correct approach. It's more of a hack that will lead to confusion. The OP most likely needs to use a list or a dictionary. There are almost never a situation where `locals`, `globals` or `exec` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is your answer

```
for x in range(5):
    x += 1
    list_name = "list_" + str(x)
    list_item = []
    print("Printing {0} = ".format(list_name), list_item)
```

Here is output:

```
Printing list_1 =  []
Printing list_2 =  []
Printing list_3 =  []
Printing list_4 =  []
Printing list_5 =  []
```